# How to Successfully navigate from ListItem screen to Details Screen (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I'm praticing Compose navigation. I made an App that displays a ListItem with images, *on what I call HomeScreen*, when a particular item is clicked it navigates to a destination containing more information/ Details, *on what I called HomeInfoScreen*. And to do this I used Navigation compose `Arugments`. I basically did this by benchmarking the [Android Developers Rally Compose](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fjetpack-compose-for-android-developers-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-navigation#6).

But the problem is **whenever I click on any of the rows it takes me to the details of the first Item, no matter which of them I click.**

I believe the problem is from coming from HomeScreen (remember, I said this was the destination I'm navigating from)

*I've previously researched, and got an Idea of passing my model object as a parameter.
But I think I did something wrong, because I get errors, and I don't know how to fix it.*

Please understand that I arranged the code, in multiple composables, in this format;
`SecondBodyElement` -> `SecondBodyGrid` ------> `HomeContentScreen`

And Finally I call `HomeContentScreen` on the `HomeScreen`.

SecondBodyElement;

```
@Composable
fun SecondBodyElement(
    @StringRes text: Int,
    @DrawableRes drawable: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onHomeCardClick: (Int) -> Unit
) {

    Surface(
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
        elevation = 10.dp,
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 12.dp, vertical = 12.dp)
            .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(corner = CornerSize(8.dp)))
            .clickable { onHomeCardClick(drawable) }
    ) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
            modifier = Modifier
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(drawable),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(300.dp)
            )
            Text(
                text = stringResource(text),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3,
                maxLines = 3,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp, vertical = 16.dp)
            )
        }

    }
}
```

SecondyBodyGrid;

```
@Composable
fun SecondBodyGrid(
    onHomeCardClick: (Int) -> Unit = {},
) {

    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(1),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(1450.dp)
        //.disabledVerticalPointerInputScroll()
    ) {
        items(SecondBodyData) { item ->
            SecondBodyElement(
                onHomeCardClick = onHomeCardClick,
                drawable = item.drawable,
                text = item.text,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(380.dp)
                    .clickable { onHomeCardClick(item.drawable + item.text) }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

HomeContentScreen;

```
@Composable
fun HomeContentScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onHomeCardClick: (String) -> Unit,
    accountType: String? = HomeInfoModel.homeInfoModelList.first().title
) {
    val homeInfo = remember(accountType) { HomeInfoModel.getHomeInfo(accountType) }
    Column(
        modifier
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .padding(vertical = 16.dp)
    ) {
        HomeQuote()
        HomeTitleSection(title = R.string.favorite_collections) {
            SecondBodyGrid { onHomeCardClick(homeInfo.title) }
        }
    }
}
```

And Finally HomeScreen;

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(onHomeCardClick: (String) -> Unit) {
    HomeContentScreen(onHomeCardClick = onHomeCardClick)
}
```

Please like I said I'm practicing, I don't know what you are going to need. But I'm going to add my NavHost (Nav Graph) and the Model file, just incase, If you need any other thing I'm more than happy to provide.

Model, HomeInfoModel;

```
data class HomeInfoData(
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val sex: String,
    val age: Int,
    val description: String,
    val homeInfoImageId: Int = 0
)


object HomeInfoModel {
    val homeInfoModelList = listOf(
        HomeInfoData(
            id = 1,
            title = "There's Hope",
            sex = "Male",
            age = 14,
            description = "Monty enjoys chicken treats and cuddling while watching Seinfeld.",
            homeInfoImageId = R.drawable.ab1_inversions
        ),
        ....
    )

    fun getHomeInfo(accountName: String?): HomeInfoData {
        return homeInfoModelList.first { it.title == accountName }
    }
}
```

My NavHost (Nav Graph);

```
....

        composable(route = Home.route) {
            HomeScreen(
                onHomeCardClick = { accountType ->
                    navController.navigateToHomeInfoScreen(accountType)
                }
            )
        }
        composable(
            route = HomeInfoDestination.routeWithArgs,
            arguments = HomeInfoDestination.arguments,
        ) { navBackStackEntry ->
            // Retrieve the passed argument
            val accountType =
                navBackStackEntry.arguments?.getString(HomeInfoDestination.accountTypeArg)

            // Pass accountType
            HomeInfoScreen(accountType)

        }

        ....
    }
}

....

private fun NavHostController.navigateToHomeInfoScreen(accountType: String) {
    this.navigateSingleTopTo("${HomeInfoDestination.route}/$accountType")
}
```

I think the problem is from the Homescreen but I don't really know, So I'm going to Add the HomeInfoScreen, Sorry making this question any longer.

HomeInfoScreen;

```
@Composable
fun HomeInfoScreen(
    accountType: String? = HomeInfoModel.homeInfoModelList.first().title
) {
    DisplayHomeInfo(accountType)
}

@Composable
fun WelcomeText() {
    Text(
        text = "Welcome, to Home Information",
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 12.dp, vertical = 18.dp)
    )
}

@Composable
fun HomeInfoDetails(
    accountType: String? = HomeInfoModel.homeInfoModelList.first().title
) {
    val homeInfo = remember(accountType) { HomeInfoModel.getHomeInfo(accountType) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(10.dp)
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = homeInfo.homeInfoImageId),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(topEnd = 4.dp, bottomEnd = 4.dp)),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Text(
            text = homeInfo.title,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Text(
            text = homeInfo.description,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5
        )
    }
}


// Step: Home screen - Scrolling
@Composable
fun DisplayHomeInfo(
    accountType: String? = HomeInfoModel.homeInfoModelList.first().title
) {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .padding(vertical = 16.dp)
    ) {
        WelcomeText()
        HomeInfoDetails(accountType)
    }
}
```

For Clarity Sake; **How can I navigate to the exact item when it is clicked on the SuccessScreen.**
I'll sinerely be greatful for any help. Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case somebody needs this, I've been able to do this. I followed a website's [Developer's Breach](https://developersbreach.com/list-detail-navigation-compose/) tutorial.